# Fourier Series of $f(x) = 0$ from $(-\pi, 0)$, $x$ from $(0,\pi)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I need to determine the fourier series of the following function, (using trig method, not complex) 
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } -\pi < x < 0, \\ 
x & \text{if } 0 < x < \pi \end{cases} $$
and then use it to show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}. $$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: @user2253455 , do you **have** to use the Fourier series of that function to obtain that sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fourier coefficients are
$$
\begin{align}
   a_{0} & = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}xdx = \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\pi^{2}}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2},\\
   a_{n} & = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}x\cos(nx)dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\left[\left.\frac{1}{n}\sin(nx)x\right|_{x=0}^{\pi}-\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin nx\,dx\right] \\
    & = \frac{1}{\pi}\left[\left.\frac{1}{n^{2}}\cos nx \right|_{x=0}^{\pi}\right]
      = \frac{\cos(n\pi)-1}{\pi n^{2}}=\frac{(-1)^{n}-1}{\pi n^{2}} \\
   b_{n} & = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}x\sin(nx) dx=
      \frac{1}{\pi}\left[\left.-\frac{1}{n}\cos(nx)x\right|_{x=0}^{\pi}+\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(nx)dx\right] \\
    & = \frac{1}{\pi}\left[-\frac{\pi}{n}\cos(n\pi)+\left.\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sin(nx)\right|_{x=0}^{\pi}\right]=-\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}
\end{align}
$$
So the Fourier Series for $f$ converges pointwise to
$$
    \frac{f(x+0)+f(x-0)}{2}=\frac{\pi}{4}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\left(\frac{(-1)^{n}-1}{\pi n^{2}}\cos(nx)-\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\sin(nx)\right)
$$
At the endpoints of $[-\pi,\pi]$, the left and right limits at $x$ are interpreted in terms of the periodic extension of $f$, which gives $\{f(-\pi+0)+f(\pi-0)\}/2=\pi/2$. Evaluate at $x=\pi$:
$$
    \frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{f(\pi-0)+f(-\pi+0)}{2}=\frac{\pi}{4}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}-1}{\pi n^{2}}(-1)^{n}=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^{2}}.
$$
Solving for the sum,
$$
    \frac{\pi^{2}}{8} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^{2}}
$$